# How to convert SKImage or SKData to String in Xamarin to be able to create a post request

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

Here I have my code (from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102674/how-to-save-finger-painting-from-skcanvasview-into-file)

```
void OnAnalyze(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var surface = SKSurface.Create(new SKImageInfo((int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Width,
                                            (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Height));
            var canvas = surface.Canvas;
            canvas.Clear();

            foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

            foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
                canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

            canvas.Flush();

            var snap = surface.Snapshot();
            var pngImage = snap.Encode();
        }
```

The code above takes what is drawn on the skcanvasview called canvasView and puts it into the variable pngImage that has the data type SKData. How would I convert pngImage or snap, which has the data type SKImage, to a string in my post request body? Below is my request code:

```
public async Task<AnalyerResults> AnalyzeWork(SKData pngImage)
        {
            HttpClient client = await GetClient();
            var result = await client.PostAsync(Url + "analyzer", new StringContent(...));
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnalyerResults>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
```

I would like the body to be in a format like using Postman for sending a post request with the body type binary with a .png file (not JSON). Thank you.

Comment: use SKData.ToArray() to get a byte array.  You probably don't want to post it as StringContent if it's binary data.

Comment: @Jason How would I convert the byte array to the data type HTTP Content?

Comment: read the docs for HttpContent and note all the subtypes, like ByteArrayContent.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Jason thank you. I tried this and it gave an error but I think this is due to my API wanting the image data as a byte string. So I tried 'var result = await client.PostAsync(Url + "analyzer", new StringContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pngImage.ToArray()), Encoding.UTF8));' however this also gave me an error. Can you please assist me with how to solve this?

Comment: "an error" is not helpful.  What is the specific error?  And what is the signature of your API endpoint?  If it excepts image data as a string, is it in Base64 or some other encoding?

Comment: @Jason The return of the variable result is null. Sorry I am new to API creation and what is a signature of an API endpoint? I believe Postman encodes the image in hexadecimal.

Comment: A method signature is the parameters and their types required by a method.

Comment: @Jason The parameter I think in this case is a byte string. My API is is in Python and I do:
image_data = flask.request.get_data() # image_data's data type is a string
image_vector = numpy.frombuffer(image_data, dtype=numpy.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image_vector, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

Comment: that appears to be expecting a byte[] not a string.  If you control the API then you should be able to debug it to figure out why it doesn't like the request you are sending.

Comment: @Jason What do you mean by control the API?

Comment: Is the API running on your server?  If it's Python, you should be able to debug it, even if you didn't write it.

Comment: @Jason Yeah it is running on Google App Engine. When I tested my API with Postman it worked so I think it is an error with the xamarin app more. Perhaps I should run the server locally and make the Xamarin app connect to there, as I am developing the app and api on different computers?

Comment: this is getting far off-course from the question you actually asked, which had to do with getting byte data from Skia.  I'd suggest you ask a new question, post your Postman session, your C# code for your request, and ask "how do I replicate this postman request in C#?"

Comment: @Jason I am going to make a new question as this is going into Python also

Comment: @Jason Sorry I did not see your previous message before I posted my comment. But yes I will definitely do that. Thank you very much for your help, sorry for my incompetence at some points.